# How to remove dot from material icons stylesheets

Tags: html, css, icons

So I'm using a stylesheet from [Google's Material Icons](https://material.io/icons/) and I place the icon on the web page using the html form they show and I'm getting this dot next to the icon when I just want to show the icon not the dot.

*The reference to the stylesheet*

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet">
```

*The list which has the image*

```
<ul style="POSITION: absolute; TOP:7%; LEFT: 90%; Color:Red">

    <li>

        <!-- This is when I call the icon -->
        <i class="material-icons">account_balance</i>

    </li>


</ul>
```

I am wondering if I'm just missing a property somewhere like a boolean for dot:true/false. I suspect it might be something to do with positioning it myself with absolute but I'm not sure.

Here is the image I am getting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndaKp.jpg)

The dot is just randomly on the left side of it and exposed, when I would like it hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  /*/OR use --list-style-type: none;-- /*/
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<ul style="POSITION: absolute; TOP:7%; LEFT: 90%; Color:Red">
  <li>
  <!-- This is when I call the icon -->
  <i class="material-icons">account_balance</i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ya no problem, thank you, I guess I didn't think it was a list item. It says it recorded the upvote but I don't got enough rep to let it show.